# how do I sort an array in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, indexing, sorting

I have this code for displaying a list from an array:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" class="listTable">
@foreach(var row in list){
    <tr>
        <td>@row[0]</td>
        <td>@row[1]</td>
        <td>@row[2]</td>
        <td>@row[3]</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**What I want is to sort the array "list" by index 3 in an ascending order before showing the list.**

I have searched for hours now, because I was sure this had been adressed before, but I found nothing. 
Could be that I am using wrong terms when searching, if so then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should consider editing the question title :)

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659866/is-there-c-sharp-support-for-an-index-based-sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SImply use `Enumerable.OrderBy<T>()`

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" class="listTable">
@foreach(var row in list.OrderBy(i=>i[3])){
    <tr>
        <td>@row[0]</td>
        <td>@row[1]</td>
        <td>@row[2]</td>
        <td>@row[3]</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. 

Well, almost - the third index is a number so it has to be like this: 
foreach(var row in list.OrderBy(i=>Convert.ToInt64(i[3]))){

otherwise it will make 100 come before 2 etc. 

I should have said the third index was numeric :P